# Downloading attachments from outlook and renaming the files depending on subject+file name from a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, win32com

So in summary what I want to happen is:

- Attachment gets downloaded into a specific folder
- Program will look at the the first word of subject (for ex. ALEXES)
- Program will look at the name of the attachment and combine it with subject name. So `portfolio.pdf` => `ALEXES-portfolio.pdf`
- Program will look into a pd.DataFrame (or any other) and see that there is a  row `(ALEXES-portfolio.pdf, ALEXES-portfolio-7/17/19.pdf)` so it will grab the entry in second column and save the file as that

Right now I have the following code:

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(r'path')
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df = df[['Short Name','File Name']]

print(df)

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
subfolder = inbox.Folders(2)

messages = subfolder.Items

for message in messages:
    attachments = message.attachments
    for attachment in attachments:
        attachment.SaveAsFile(r'path' + '\\'+'test' + str(attachment))
        print(format(attachment))
```

So far I have this code that downloads the files to a designated folder and prints the first word of the subject. Please link any documentation/ learning material as everything is very new for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my program to work and hope this helps someone in the future. Also added an exception to a rule,

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
import sys
from io import StringIO

pd.set_option('display.width', pd.util.terminal.get_terminal_size()[0])
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")

inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6)
subfolder = inbox.Folders(2)
messages = subfolder.Items

base = pd.read_excel(r'path to excel file with names')
base = pd.DataFrame(base)
base = base[['Short Name','File Name']]

#print(base)

from datetime import date
data = []
for message in messages:
    sub = ()
    attachments = message.attachments
    subjects = message.Subject
    split = subjects.split()
    df = pd.DataFrame(split)
    df = (df[0:1])
    first = split[0]
    apollo_list = (exceptions)


    for attachment in attachments:
        try:
            if first in apollo_list:
                attachment.SaveAsFile(r'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Python' + '\\' + 
                first + '-' + 'statement.xls')
            else:
                attach_name = [first + '-' + str(attachment)]
                df1 = pd.DataFrame(attach_name,columns=['Short Name'])
                df2 = df1.merge(base)
                df2 = df2.iloc[0 ,1]
                attachment.SaveAsFile(r'C:\\Users\\user\\Downloads\\Python' + '\\' + 
                df2)

        except:
            print('Not to be sent in SFTP : ' + first + '-' + str(attachment))
```